# C# Comunicación entre aplicaciones

Tags: c#, windows-forms, windows

Necesito crear una aplicación con modularidad que gestiones el numero de usuarios máximos con rol administrador, para poder saber cuantos usuarios administrador existen en mi aplicación en maquinas remotas intente usar variables de ambiente, pero en muchos de los casos estas se duplican o simplemente no se recuperan.
Mi problema consiste en que la aplicación de escritorio no lee las variables de ambiente remotas, dado que al buscar los procesos no las recupera.
¿como puedo obtener variables a partir de los procesos?

```
Process currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
string pid = currentProcess.Id.ToString();
Console.WriteLine("I am: " + pid);
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcessesByName("contador supervisores");
        
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("dddfotmatsasa", textBox1.Text,EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
        foreach (Process process in processlist)
        {
            var env = process.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables;
            string path = env["dddfotmatsasa"];
                MessageBox.Show( string.Format("Process: {0} ID: {1} Window title: {2} 
                variable: {3} username: {4}", process.ProcessName, process.Id, 
               process.MainWindowTitle,path,process.StartInfo.UserName));
        }
```

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Es medio confusa tu pregunta.. podrias explicar mejor tu problema? que tienen que ver las variables de entorno con la comunicacion de procesos? que procesos queres comunicar? como es tu aplicacion?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente lo que estas preguntando.

Comment: Explica de manera general lo que intentas hacer y despues el problema especifico en tu codigo. No se entiendo tu duda.